# which version of C# to use $ instead of string.format

Tags: c#, string.format, dollar-sign

I find a piece of code like this

```
int a = 100;
string str = $"{a:0.00}";
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

the result is "100.00"

The $ have the same function of string.Format, and I want to know which version of C#.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx), and it's part of C# 6, which was released in July as part of Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 2):

A `C# 6.0` feature, [`string interpolation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx).

Comment: Down voter, please let me know the reason for down voting? Will improve the answer, it won't help down voting without reason.

Comment: Your answer is right. I didn't give the down voting.

Comment: I know it is not You @JerryChou, someone just down voted without the reason, it is annoying such case.

Comment: I'm sorry, when I have 15 reputation, I give my best vote to you~